# Can change field of checkbox for select in the time of render symfony2 twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I render one form

```
$builder
       ->add('nomeCell')
       ->add('mesa',EntityType::class, array(
                'class'=>'AppBundle:Mesa',
                'choice_label'=>'descricao',
            ))
       ->add('produto', CategoryType::class)
```

in twig Produto

```
{% if produtos %}
  {% for produto in produtos %}
     {% if produto.categoria.id == categoria.id and produto.ativo==1  %}
        {{ produto.descricao }} R$ {{ produto.valor | number_format(2, ',', '.') }}
        <br>
     {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

How i not set what's type of field will render, can i change inside twig?

Example:

```
{% if produto.principal == 1 %}
  //render select option
{% else %}
  //render checkbox
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I don't see any form field in your twig Producto ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a event listener on your form. Check the documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-underlying-data) for more information.